# How to unwrap return value at function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to simplify the problem, the simple code is below. how can I pass two/any arguments(which comes from another function return value) to the `test` method? Is it possible, or we can't do it in python?

```
def values(x, y):
    return (x,y)

def test(x, y):
    print(x,y)

# error at below 
test(value(1,2))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unpack using `*`:

```py
test(*value(1,2)) # >>> test(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need tuple unpacking:

```
test(*value(1,2))
```